# Functions for IBActions in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a bunch of IB Actions on my main storyboard, all triggered by buttons on top of text labels. So you tap button 1, it executes code label 1, you tap button 2, it executes code for label 2, and so on.

I know I'm doing something wrong if I'm writing out nearly identical code for each IBAction. In ActionScript (back in the day!) I'd just write a function, and reference the instance name for each button and label.

I've included a simplified segment of the code below. It's working fine, I just want to make it efficient, but am not sure of how to do this in Xcode. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
- (IBAction)firstBtnPressed {

    self.firstLabel.text = rightNow;

}

- (IBAction)secondBtnPressed {

    self.secondLabel.text = rightNow;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there is little difference if you have several methods with almost identical code than if you have just one method with a big if-else or switch statements trying to figure out what button was pressed (unless you have no more than 2 or 3 buttons).

I'm not familiar with your exact requirements but what I would do (and I'm making some assumptions about what you need. I may be wrong) is find a way of relating the `UIButton`s with the `UILabel`s. One way of doing this is creating my own `UIButton` subclass that has a label as a property:

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *theLabel;

@end
```

In this way you can relate `button1` with `label1`, `button2` with `label2`, etc. The advantage of doing that is you can write just the following code and it will work:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[MyButton class]]) {

        MyButton *button = (MyButton*)sender;
        button.theLabel.text = rightNow;
    }
}
```

And that's it. No big if-else or switch statements. No duplicated code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this seems exactly right--I have 9 buttons, so relating them in the way you've suggested seems sensible. Thanks so much, Luis!

Comment: @user2938418, let me know if you have more questions. Also, if the answer is helpful please remember to accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is totally fine. If you wanted, you could give the `UIButton`'s a tag value in IB and then combine the methods (set both of their actions to this same method):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    if (button.tag == 0) {
        self.firstLabel.text = rightNow;
    } else if (button.tag == 1) {
        self.secondLabel.text = rightNow;
    }
}
```

You could also use a switch:

```
switch (button.tag) {
    case 0:
        self.firstLabel.text = rightNow;
        break;
    case 1:
        self.secondLabel.text = rightNow;
        break;      
    default:
        break;
}
```

I think this is what you are after. If I misunderstood something please let me know.

#### Edit:

Given that you have 9 of these I would personally change my approach a bit. You could either put them all into an array and access them `[self.myLabels[button.tag] setText:rightNow];` but this will still require 9 IBOutlets. Although not problematic it is a lot of them.

Another thing you could do is give them all a tag that is say 20 points higher than the corresponding button and do something like this inside the IBAction:

```
UIView *viewToChange = [self.view viewWithTag:button.tag+20];
// used to protect yourself since IB allows the multiple views to have the same tag
if ([viewToChange isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
    ((UILabel *)viewToChange).text = rightNow;
}
```

This is simple but it does tightly bind your logic to your tag values for both your buttons and labels. The upside to this is simple logic and no IBOutlets for all of your UILabels!

Comment: `switch(button.tag)` might be better?  (Unless there's only 2 buttons)

Comment: @nhgrif I was working on it when you commented :) (thanks btw!)

Comment: Also, alternatively, he can put his labels in an array where the indices correspond to the button tags and just do this all in a single line.  `self.arrOfLabels[button.tag] = rightNow;`

Comment: This is great, and very helpful, thank you. There are 9 buttons total, so it seems like the switch approach is preferable here. Is there a way to similarly name the label instances so that I can avoid repeating the code for each label? Basically, tapping the button over any label leads to that particular label being set to the text rightNow. Thank you!

Comment: Man, you guys are fast - my question was answered before I had time to ask it. Many thanks!

Comment: @user2938418 take a look at my edits, they may/may not help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add each UIButton as a property, then check which one is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)tappedButton:(id)sender {

    if ( sender == _button1){

        NSLog(@"Button 1 pressed");
    }
    //....
}
```

You need to select "sender" as the argument while connecting the action outlet. Now you can connect all buttons to the same outlet.

Comment: Like my comment to the other answer, this one can also be written as a `switch` statement.  A little less intuitive, but `switch(sender) { case _button1:` etc., should work.